# SSH on mac 10.11.5 suddenly stopped working

Tags: ssh, ansible, osx-elcapitan

SSH was working nicely on mac 10.11.5 for a long time now.
Suddenly after installing `Ansible` it stopped working.
All I get when I try to connect to remote host is
this. Note: I gave replaced the server IP address with a dummy one.

```
iMac:~ mohamedsaleh$ ssh -v root@123.456.789.000
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 123.456.789.000 [138.68.60.62] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mohamedsaleh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

Update: I have tried on several machines and all have the same issue.

Update2: I have tried using VPN and it works normally, after investigation it seems that my ISP have closed that port for random reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete your locally stored ssh keys

> Here is quick fix that worked for me

Go to the directory that stores your ssh keys

```
cd ~/.ssh/
```

Remove the known_hosts folder that has all your ssh keys that you previously used

```
rm known_hosts
```

Try to connect again to your remote server and provide your password once prompted.

Comment: I have done that and it don't solve the problem. When I used a `VPN` it works. 
I have contacted ISP `TEData` and they didn't acknowledge any of that but I think they have blocked it, but not sure, yet